# Link is not clickable after first time

Tags: html, css

I am working in a CMS based project where I have a left side navigation and content area.
While I click on the menu for first time, it works as expected i.e clickable  but If I click for the second time,it(i.e the link) did not work as expected.

Let me give you the link ,
[visit sandbox](http://e2cindia.co/)

**Note:** In index2.html there is a class called main-wrapper, now when I remove that class , the navigation works perfectly.

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: <div class="sidebar"> is over the links. work on the css. Firefox and F12 is a great thing to check existing code.

Comment: Please add the information that is needed to answer the question, to the question itself, and not behind a link. This post wont have any value to others if that link dies or if the problem is fixed. Also see how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the below css in your css file or in inside head tag and your sidebar will now work.

```
.main-wrapper-dashboard .sidebar {
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

Your main sidebar had been overlapped by the secondary sidebar in index2.html thats why you were not able to click the links.

Comment: Not working sir @Surya Neupane

Comment: try adding !important to the above code. If not working show me your whole code of the page and css.

Comment: Ya, its working sir :)

Comment: good good welcome

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your page I observed that `main-wrapper main-wrapper-pages` come over `main-wrapper main-wrapper-dashboard` so you can not click on `main-wrapper main-wrapper-dashboard` so try to add z-index to that:

```
.main-wrapper.main-wrapper-dashboard {
    z-index: 100;  //any value more than 10
}
```

Comment: Why am I downvoted for this answer?

Comment: Maybe he down-voted anyone whose answer didn't immediately work for him? Your answer works so I have voted you up

Comment: No he can not down vote because he has only reputation 45